# Vbs on Excel Starter 2010: activex component can't create object Excel.Application

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a new pc with Windows 7 and **Office Starter 2010** pre-installed. If I launch the following simple vb script (from command line: cscript testScript.vbs):

```
Dim xlApp
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.application")
xlApp.visible = True
Set xlWorkbooks = xlApp.Workbooks
Set xlWorkbook = xlWorkbooks.Open("C:\path\myFile.xls")
xlWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows("1:2").AutoFit
xlApp.visible = False
xlWorkbook.Save
xlWorkbook.Close("C:\path\myFile.xls")
xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

it returns this error: **activex component can't create object 'Excel.Application'**.
I don't understand if the error is due to Starter limitations (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/starter-help/excel-features-that-are-not-fully-supported-in-excel-starter-HA010374501.aspx), and I found dissenting opinions on the web.

Is there a way to make it works using Office Starter version?

Answer (score 1):

Despite this is already very aged question, I haved decided to post the following information only to help other googlers.

Since you are trying to create an instance of **Excel.Application** outside VBA, there's a good chance of being succeeded if you install an updated version of [Microsoft Excel Viewer](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-pt/download/details.aspx?id=10) on target machine. This will allow you to access **Excel's API**.

Bear in mind, that **Excel Starter Edition** does not support macros, along with [other important limitations](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Use--Excel-Starter-2010-with-earlier-versions-of-Excel-4cdae7ad-0cdd-44e9-9ce8-f6b9551c612b?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB#bm3g).

Cheers!

Comment: It didn't work for me. Installing the whole Office didn't solve the problem either.